# How can I search a table for a timestamp x hours old in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, timestamp

I am trying to search for timestamps in a Cassandra table that are within a given length of time. For example, "all timestamp that are 4 hours or less old".

I have tried using DATESUB(), TIMEDIFF() and other ways to find a time delta, but just haven't had any luck. I am not sure if I am just looking at this from a relational DB mindset.

EDIT: Adding an example below

```
SELECT *  
FROM events  
WHERE event_timestamp < (now() - 4 hours) -- This part is giving issues  
ORDER BY region DESC;
```

Thanks!

Comment: please add a minimal example of what you want people to look at.

Comment: I just added an example.